# Excel Formula for Summary Page

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to do a summary sheet.

I created a drop down list of names: Bob, Jack, Beth and a drop down list of two options: Completed or Corrections Pending.

On Sheet2 next to the task you would select the name and then one of the two options.

On the summary sheet I need to create a formula that check the whole range that has the names to see how many task Bob has "Completed" or "Corrections Pending".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A10, "Bob", B1:B10, "Completed")
```

That's assuming all of the names are within cells A1:A10 and all of the tasks are within cells B1:B10.  Do the same for "Corrections Pending."

Comment: COUNTIFS is exclusive to Excel 2007 and up.